# Не отключается камера в genymotion

Tags: android-sdk, android-studio, genymotion

Пользуюсь genymotion эмулятором для android.

Есть необходимость сделать проверку: как будет вести себя программа на устройствах без камеры или 1 камерой. При выполнении такого кода возвращаются 2 камеры, хотя поставил камеру в genymotion в off, и должно быть 0.

```
int numCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
```

Я пользуюсь linux, может не все features были в пакете?